# mysql performance estimate for 100,000 entries

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm having a hard time finding benchmark figures for MySql performance..

There are a lot of sites out there, with figures, but they vary so much, I'm not
 sure if it is what I am after..

My question is:

I have a single table with the following structure.

```
          email .. 64 bytes max
          firstname .. 24 bytes max
          lastname .. 24 bytes max
          gender .. 1 byte max
          age .. 3 bytes max
          password .. 32 bytes max
```

Assuming a completely empty table,. how long would it take for me
 to generate 100,000 of these entries ( just using randomly generated values )
 and insert them into my database..

Does MySql insert them, and sort them lazily in the background or when needed ?

I'm assuming all 100,000 entries are added to the table and all colums fully sortable
 as soon it is done.. ( this point is critical,, I need an estimate figure, with a
 fully sorted table )

Comment: Why not write a simple PHP script generating 100 000 random values and inserting them in MySQL yourself? You will have a benchmark pertinent to your usecase and can change table parameters (add index for example on some columns) and see what changes

Comment: 100k entries are nothing. It still depends on machine but it probably very fast operation

Comment: Exactly what @koopajah said. The performance characteristics will be specific to (1) The hardware you're running on (2) The version of MySQL you're using (3) The code you're using to insert the data. There's no way for us to give you a meaningful/useful answer to the "performance characteristics" part of this question. **Try it yourself if you want an accurate, useful measurement**.

Answer (score 0):

The part of your question that is addressable is:

> Does MySql insert them, and sort them lazily in the background or when needed ?

Take a look at this page from the MySQL documentation, [14.2.9. MySQL and the ACID Model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html). Any database server that implements the ACID model basically "promises" that when you write data to it, by the time control returns to your code that write will either have succeeded or failed.

To the best of my knowledge, indexes will be updated at the point at which the record is inserted into the database.